# Woo-commerce tax customization

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Please check this screenshot : http://awesomescreenshot.com/03458rhf52

I have created **wordpress** website with **woocommerce** plugin.
I have to add **tax calculation** for all countries and it will be " 21% ".
But if **country = Netherlander** and Order Type (Created custom field via register fields) = "**Real**" then tax will be " **0** "(Zero). and If I select Order Type = "**Private**" then again tax will be " **21**% ".

I have tried many ways but failed.

If you have any suggestions then please tell me.

Thanks and Regards,
Nimesh P.

Comment: Can you provide the code with what is not working?

Comment: Are you using a VAT plugin? We use https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-eu-vat-assistant/ and it's been great. It'll generate (you have to go to the tax screen) the per-country breakouts.

Comment: thanks for help. But now we have changed the way for it.